# Using repeater to display Thumbnail images that link to full images

Tags: php, jquery, html, image, jquery-masonry

i'm using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin with the repeater field to display images in a masonry gallery, I want to be able to have the images in the gallery be displayed as thumbnails then when clicked they open into a lightbox, I have it all working other than the masonry images aren't showing as thumbnails (Meaning theres alot of full HD images being loaded when the page is opened causing slow loading times, heres the website page - http://vn.deckchairdesign.co.uk/wedding/weddings/ (I should add this is a Wordpress theme I am creating!).
Here's the code :

```
<?php if(get_field('images')): ?>
                <?php while(the_repeater_field('images')): ?>
                        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image'), 'full'); ?>
                        <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image'), 'thumbnail'); ?>
                        <div class="item">

                        <!-- Lightbox Image's -->       
                        <a href="<?php the_sub_field('image');?>" class="fancybox" rel="gallery_group"> 
                        <!-- Thumbnail Image's -->  
                        <img src="<?php the_sub_field('image');?>"
                        </a>

                        </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Use `phpthumb` to make the thumbnail of images

Comment: Sorry i'm new to all this stuff, where do i use this? There are already thumbnail images in the uploads folder, i need to know how to pull them to use as the masonry images.